# jasmine expect statement does not execute in protractor scenario

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Unfortunately, I don't have good recreation steps. This only happens on my computer.

Some of my tests seem to run just fine, but none of the expect actually execute. With other test the browser comes up and goes down before loading the page. Might be the same issue.

I have a test with:

```
expect(page.courseTitle.getText()).toBe 'Symphony'
expect(page.courseTitle.getText()).toBe 'garbage'
```

I expect this to fail, but it does not. If I add the line:

```
expect(true).toBe false
```

The test fails with both errors. If I add the line:

```
expect(true).toBe true
```

the test does not fail at all.

Comment: When you say the browser goes up and down before loading the page, is your `page.courseTitle.getText()` working? Try it as `page.courseTitle.getText().then(function(actualText) { console.log(actualText); expect(actualText).toBe('Symphony'); });`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare the string values, use `toEqual()` matcher:

```
expect(page.courseTitle.getText()).toEqual('Symphony');
```

> `expect(true).toBe false`
>   `expect(true).toBe true`

Should not you call `toBe` here:

```
expect(true).toBe(false);
expect(true).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
expect(page.courseTitle.getText()).toBe('Symphony');
expect(page.courseTitle.getText()).toBe('garbage')
expect(true).toBeTruthy();
expect(true).toBeFalsy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the point. The line with garbage should fail, but does not, unless I add an expect that can be executed synchronously.

BTW This does not happen on our build machine, only on my computer.

I did find a a test that works, and worked backwards from that. 
Adding this code caused the expects to execute:

```
afterEach ->
   browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then (browserLogs)->
       # Do some work here
```

It is almost as if the test do not wait for the promises to be fulfilled before exiting.